# Using SET !VAR1 EVAL with javascript iMacros

Tags: javascript, url, imacros

I have a .js iMacros file for go to url, it looks like this:

```
for ( var k = 0; k<3; k++){
var congdong; 
congdong =  "CODE:";
congdong +=  "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
congdong +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
congdong +=  "SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var letters = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5','link6','link7','link8']; var  results = []; for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {var pos = parseInt(Math.random()  * (letters.length - 1));results.push(letters[pos]);letters.splice(pos, 1);} results[i];\")" + "\n";
congdong +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
congdong +=  "URL GOTO={{!VAR1}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(congdong)
}
```

My goal is for it to run 3 times each time going to 1 different url. But when I let it run it does not go to any urls and does not report errors. Any ideas on how I could get this working?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe?

```
// ...
congdong += "SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var links = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5','link6','link7','link8']; links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];\")" + "\n";
// ...
```

---

Bear in mind, if you use

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

you won't see any errors.

Comment: Each loop it goes to another different link. 
thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 1):

my code is running

```
var linkcd= [
'link1',
'link2',
'link3',
'link4',
'link5',
'link6',
'link7'
];
var resultscd = [];
for (var k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
var pos = parseInt(Math.random() * (linkcd.length - 1));
resultscd.push(linkcd[pos]);
linkcd.splice(pos, 1);
}

for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
var congdong; 
congdong =  "CODE:";
congdong +=  "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
congdong +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
congdong +=  "SET !VAR1 \"" + resultscd[k] + "\"\n";
congdong +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
congdong +=  "URL GOTO={{!VAR1}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(congdong)
}
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested this due to an issue with my browser, please check the below code and let me know if this fixes your problem!

```
var letters = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5','link6','link7','link8']; 
for ( var k = 0; k < 3; k++){
    iimset("POS", letters[parseInt(Math.random()  * (letters.length - 1))]);
    var congdong;
    congdong =  "CODE:";
    congdong +=  "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
    congdong +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
    congdong +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
    congdong +=  "URL GOTO={{POS}}" + "\n";
    iimPlay(congdong)
}
```

Comment: @Jinjin Did this answer help you?

Comment: @JinjinDa kindly close the question if your issue was solved, you're welcome :)